# There is no tracking information for the current branch. GIT problem

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

```
kholo@LAPTOP-UMTQFP22 ~/Code/js (origin/JS-BASICS/CORE/04-functions)
λ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> origin/JS-BASICS/CORE/04-functions
```

I'm having a problem when I switch branches and run code . it opens vs code with the content of the previous branch even though at the bottom left it says that I'm in the new branch. I was told to try git pull first and then git checkout and then run code . to open the branch in vs code. Will be very thankful for the help.

Comment: Side note: you're on a *local* branch (because you can only be on local branches—actually, the phrase "local branch" is redundant, as the other things are not actually *branches* in the first place) whose name is `origin/JS-BASICS/CORE/04-functions`. That's a bad name for a (local) branch as it looks like a remote-tracking name. *Git* won't get confused, but you will: the remote-tracking name that goes with this name is `origin/origin/JS-BASICS/CORE/04-functions`.

Comment: You probably should rename this (local) branch to a more sensible name. As Rodolfo BocaneGra answered, be careful with mixing case. Git was designed on Linux and thinks that "readme" and "README" are separate names and that you should be able to use both at the same time; WIndows thinks they're the same name, with different case, and will only allow you to use one at a time; when Windows and Git clash here, the result is to make the user (i.e., you) miserable, rather than to do something sensible or useful.

Comment: I'm impressed that Git doesn't get confused. I suppose that's because it checks the ref against the local branch names first.

Comment: (As a result, my general rule here is *never use any uppercase anywhere* in file names or branch names, if at all possible. Sometimes you have no choice though.)

Comment: @matt: yes, it checks branch names first (see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) and note the order of the six steps taken to resolve an ambiguous ref-name—technically Git checks *tag* names first, but presumably there is no conflicting tag here...).

Answer (score 0):

You are suposed to change to the branch you want to pull changes, E.g. `dev`, `myFeature` or `john-doe` by doing:

`git checkout myBranchName`

Be careful with misspelings or upper/lower case letters, this is a common issue when starting on git, after changed to the right branch you can do `git pull` to pull your desired changes.

Comment: hey, thank you for your help really appreciate it. Just to clarify I'm already in the new branch but the content of the previous branch is showing up on this branch. I tried doing git pull that message pops up.

Comment: I think you should clone again in a new folder, maybe a configuration or something went wrong